# How to get around SoapUI lowercasing all urls?

Tags: soapui, case-sensitive

We have an url like `https://domain.example/rsvs_TargetService/Action`as the endpoint url which, when used as a SoapUI endpoint, gets lowercased to `https://domain.example/rsvs_targetservice/action` which doesn't work.

Is there a way to get around that?

Note: since SoapUI is a tool commonly used by programmers, I think this should be in scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR; this is now fixed in SoapUI version 5.3 onwards.

---

This was a [known bug from around version 4.6 onwards](https://sourceforge.net/p/soapui/bugs/687/).

The workaround I found was to have a groovy test step before the request test step, containing value like

```
context['path'] = 'rsvs_TargetService/Action'
```

And referring to that in HTTP request step like

```
https://domain.example/${path}
```

Then, when you run the entire test case, the variable expansion will do its magic.

SoapUI source code is in github, and there was [a pull request merged fixing this](https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui/pull/216). The pull request was merged 16.8.2016, and was [released as part of 5.3 release](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Feature-Requests/Allow-uppercase-in-URL-in-the-HTTP-Request-test-step/idi-p/105272), which is publicly available, so current versions should no longer have this issue..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using context, and running an additional groovy script, define custom test case / suite / project level property.

For eg: define Project level property, say `URL_PATH_TS_ACTION` with value `rsvs_TargetService/Action`

Then set the `endpoint` to use [Property Expansion](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html). i.e.,
 `https://domain.example/${#Project#URL_PATH_TS_ACTION}`

This way, an unwanted groovy script can be avoided.

Of course, you may entirely externalize the endpoint using above method. To do so (also shown in the screen shot)

- double click on service interface
- go to Service Endpoints
- click on +
- add endpoint as shown with property expansion
- select one of the endpoint
- click on Assign & select all requests and test requests

You will be able to switch the endpoint easily for all of your tests.
[image]

Comment: I don't see how that would work, as `${#Project#URL_PATH_TS_ACTION}` as an endpoint value will be lowercased as well, breaking it?

Comment: From the [link I gave in my answer](https://sourceforge.net/p/soapui/bugs/687/): "I use property values like "${#Project#GlobalDTEndpoint}" in the URL field (which has worked fine in 4.5.2). If I try to edit these value in more recent versions, the string is converted to lower case, causing the testcase to fail."